# multithread server doesn't continue to execute whenever a client get disconnected

Tags: c, multithreading, network-programming, posix

hi there i'm working on a multithread Server (TCP) in C and i have a little issue about it. Everything works fine, more than one thread can connect to the server but whenever a client writes "exit" (which is a condition for a client when he/she writes "exit" string he/she goes to disconnect from the server) serves shutsdown itself also. So the communication through other threads get lost. However, logically it should be waiting for other clients even some current clients get disconnected. Here is a part of main and server is in a endless loop for waiting clients. `hsock` is id of socket belongs to server and `csock` is the id of clients.

```
main(){
.
.
.


while(1){

    if(counter==0)
        printf("waiting for a connection\n");

    csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    if((*csock = accept( hsock, (struct sockaddr*)&sadr, &addr_size))!= -1){
    printf("---------------------\nReceived connection from %s\n",inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
        pthread_create(&thread_id,0,&SocketHandler, (void*)csock );
        counter++;
    }

    else{
     fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %d\n", errno);
    }
        }// end while
.
.
.
return 0
}
```

As you can see whenever a client get disconnected, server should keep waiting for an another threads. On the other hand, this is the last part of `SocketHandler` function which is a thread function.

```
void* SocketHandler(void* csock){
.
.
.

        printf("Client disconnected\n");
        free(csock);
        return 0;
    }
```

After `return 0` statement isn't it necessary to return back to `while(1)` loop in main. I will be glad if you can help and thanks anyway

Comment: Where is/are the declaration/s of `csock`?

Comment: i didnt want to write whole code to make it less understandable but if you think it would be more helpfull i can add the declarations. and also they declared above of the while(1) statement

Comment: "*... shuts down itself ...*" in which way? Clean or crash?

Comment: Ok, so `csock` isn't a global? Sry, but I just was irritated by the `free(csock)`.

Comment: its a crash i guess. Nope `csock` is local.

Comment: Build the server using `-g -Wall` and run it in `gdb` then you'll see what happens.

Comment: Shouldn't the code (in SockHandler) read "free(id);" and not free(csock)? How is this even compiling if csock is local?

Comment: @Neo it was a mistake when i copy the code here. so its local

Comment: @alk could you help about compiling with gdb and also -g -Wall cause i'm not familiar to terminal in UBUNTU.

Comment: So you use an IDE? Which one please? @quartaela

Comment: @alk no friend i dont use any IDE :) i'm compiling with gcc in UBUNTU terminal but i dont know how to use some specific terms when compiling except some simple terms like gcc

Comment: `gdb` is a debugger (see `man gdb`). You could run your program through it, even step be step. To be able to see your code in there the code needs to be compiled using the (additional) option `-g`. The (`gcc`) option `-Wall` is not needed for the debugger, but still helps debugging: It enables all warnings `gcc` might see during compilation. Fix your code until `gcc` issues no more warnings.

Comment: you said that the server crashes, are you sure? Can you give the terminal output after the program termination, if it's an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads run asynchronously once created, which means that the main thread (the one doing the `accept`) should continue looping and be back to accepting new connections, whatever the child thread does.

Some advices:

- if your thread can run autonomously, use `pthread_detach` after the create to let thread handle its own termination graciously.
- don't forget to do a `close(csock)` before ending the thread.
- you don't necessarily need to allocate the int which will contain the socket descriptor, just pass it as the `void *` directly (but I guess that you will be passing more information than just the socket in a structure in a future version of your code).

Comment: well i handled the problem with a `return` statement in `SocketHandler` function and used the main termination functions properly. So thanks for your help informative reply.

Answer (score 0):

> After return 0 statement isn't it necessary to return back to while(1)
>   loop in main.

No. The thread exits. It has nothing to so with what happens in other threads.

I don't see how you can expect anybody to help you with a networking problem that happens on client disconnect when you don't show any code that handles the networking to the client.

Comment: the reason why i didnt share the code was it consists of a huge and messy code which would make harder to understand. client just does a send and receive operations via network. On the other hand, i guess i fixed the issue with a return statement in `SocketHandler`. But if you wanna see the code of thread i can share